# Expression language to treat "-" sign as string literal instead of minus operator?

Tags: java, jsp, el

I have empId as 500 and custId as 200. I want the el to return me  result as "500-200". I tried below expression which returns me 300
(i.e substracting 200 from 500).

How to make "as" sting literal instead of subtract operator

```
"${sessionScope.empId-sessionScope.custId}")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply get it out of the EL expression :

```
${sessionScope.empId}-${sessionScope.custId}
```

Comment: see my update, Actually i was able to do it but not under taglib